# shopify - Gift wrap option for all the products

Tags: shopify

I am following the instructions mentioned at http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/add-a-gift-wrap-option

But what I am trying to achieve is add a gift option to all the products. When trying to do so I am setting up the linked list to link to "All products"

But in cart I am getting message as "You attempted to add a gift-wrapping script to your shopping cart, but it won't work because you don't have a link list with handle gift-wrapping which, in turn, contains a link to your gift-wrapping product. Please " . How can I add the gift cart option to all the items - without creating separate link for each product. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this code to work you will need to point your link at the 'Gift Wrap' product, not at 'All Products'. If this still doesn't work, I would suggest revisiting step 2 of the Shopify instructions and make sure your linklist has the correct title and handle.